# Increasing height of 27" iMac

Tags: imac, ergonomics

I struggle with my 27" iMac, with its fixed size and weight, to have it sit at a comfortable eye sight position for me when I look down at my screen.

If your neck aches because the monitor is too high, a few recommendations are available [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/258927/7985) and on [macrumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ergonomics-of-27-imac.1685495/). I'm soliciting a solution for the opposite problem dismissing:

- [Drilling holes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imRzvrZiGZM) to introduce VESA compatibility.
- Introducing a clash with the fine lines of the iMac by putting it on top of [one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42194/7985) or a few books or reams of paper.
- Getting an [absurd-looking box](https://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/HA243ZM/B/twelve-south-hirise-stand-for-imac) to solve a problem that was contrived in the first place.

Is there another method to make the 27" iMac ergonomic for someone a bit taller than average who does not wish to keep his head dangling over his body while looking down at the monitor?

Comment: The question is becoming kind of broad. Are you looking for options (then please move the things you've already found into an answer) or do you need help in implementing/building one specific solution (then maybe the list of alternatives is rather confusing).

Comment: @patrix I agree. Although none of my updates is satisfactory, they're really (attempts at) answers. I'll move to one answer if no one provides the holy grail of solutions. So far that holy grail, for me, is to use an old stand, although I dare not speak the name of the brand (Dell distributes fine stands with the Ultrasharp line).

Comment: Dell is just fine. The box / design /  pile of books is clear that you want a iMac to look natural / harmonious. Any stand would have to be aluminum or visually similar and pleasing. This is about personalizing a workspace, so some subjectivity has to be encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can separate the possible solutions into *intrinsic* and *extrinsic* solutions, as well as *sitting/standing* solutions.

**Intrinsic solutions** (ones that will not look like an afterthought):

- You can "[b]uy [an] *[iMac with Built-in VESA Mount Adapter](https://www.apple.com/us/shop/buy-mac/imac-vesa)*". You will not see this option on the usual checkout lane, but Google [locates](https://www.google.com/search?q=imac%20vesa%20mount&ie=utf-8) it.

The 27" iMac weighs [21 pounds (9.54 kg)](https://www.apple.com/imac/specs/). This could make it challenging to couple it with some random monitor arm on the market.

**Extrinsic solutions** (an additional base with a potentially jarring look):

- [Rain Design mBase Stand](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HHLL2ZM/A/rain-design-mbase-stand-for-27-imac?fnode=8a) for 27" iMac, $69.95
- [Bretford MobilePro Desk Mount](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/TY173LL/A/bretford-mobilepro-desk-mount?fnode=8a), $179.95
- A [custom solution](https://arstechnica.com/staff/2012/03/my-kit-2008-mac-pro/) that matches the desk rather than the iMac.
- Satechi produces a [plastic](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/computer/accessories/monitor-stands/aluminum-monitor-stand) and an [aluminum](http://www.satechi.net/index.php/aluminum-monitor-stand) stand. They're not adjustable, but breakage is less of an issue than with glass.
- Fitueyes [clear Computer Monitor Riser 4.7"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01A0EZZVE) (thanks, Allan)
- Halter [Acrylic Monitor Stand / Monitor Riser 3.675"H](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01JB359FW)

The trouble here may be that you're designing a desk for just one person. If you are pursuing a more fluid [ambiance](http://www.economist.com/news/business/21721423-their-eccentric-buildings-offer-clues-about-how-people-will-work-technology-firms-and-office) at an office and wish to accommodate someone ranging from, say, 5ft to 6ft 2", the presence of a base may not be too convenient.

**Sit/stand solutions**

- Ikea sells a [manual](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S49084965/) and an [electric](http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S59022528/) adjustable desk. They are sitting/standing desks, and so they are a much more general solution for problems in ergonomics. To use while sitting, you will need to look for a really deep keyboard tray (or possibly get a second lower table to position underneath, if you won't find that setup particularly jarring).
- Ergotron [WorkFit-A, Sit-Stand Workstation](http://www.ergotron.com/en-us/products/product-details/24-414#/), [$595](https://apple.ergotron.com/products/workfit-a#en)
- Varidesk [standing desk Pro Plus](https://www.varidesk.com/), $395 to $595.

Note that neither the Ergotron nor the Varidesk solve the problem since the height difference between the keyboard and the monitor platform is constant. A monitor pedestal will still be needed.

**To conclude**, your best bet may be to look for a sit/stand desk ([google](https://www.google.com/?q=sit%20stand%20desk)/[bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=sit%20stand%20desk)) and hook an adjustable keyboard tray ([google](https://www.google.com/?q=adjustable%20keyboard%20tray)/[bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=adjustable%20keyboard%20tray)) underneath. Unfortunately that's not a cheap option.

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising: http://www.imacmount.com/order.html
It was the first thing that came up when I googled it, but I'm sure there are other similar options as well. Good luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find the software and evaluate it themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: Not sure. If I'll be stuck with the original base hanging out stupidly like a sticking tongue, I'd rather save the $80 for this unnecessary (but patented) contraption and drill the holes.

Comment: How about this: drilling the holes, and sawing off the original stand would be better for me, but would slash the resale value.