# Do Apple brick-and-mortar stores carry the iMac with built-in VESA Mount Adapter?

Tags: imac, ergonomics

If not, what does apple do to aid & prevent the pain of using their products?

from [Increasing height of 27" iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282418/increasing-height-of-27-imac)

Comment: As found by following one of the links in the AskDifferent question posted above, [this VESA mount device](http://www.imacmount.com/order.html) from iMacMounts work very, very well. I used one for several years until the iMac bit the dust and I upgraded to a Mac Mini and an external Dell monitor. Well worth US$78.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking *how/why Apple does something is outside the scope of what can be asked as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).*

Comment: We cannot speak for Apple on both points. You'll have to contact the Apple Store in question to see if they stock it (this is not any different from any other retail store) As for the second, we can't tell you how Apple will respond to a customer perceived frustration point.

Comment: Allan - the question is poorly phrased and I assume was not intended to be a query about how or why Apple does things. My answer below (about ordering online) makes it clear that iMacs with integral VESA mounts can be made available for pickup at brick-and-mortar Apple Stores. TBH, I flagged this question as being off topic until I did a little research, and had no idea that iMacs were available with this modification to begin with. Let's give @productiveuser a chance to edit the question to remove the useless verbiage and be more specific. The _title_ of the question is quite specific.

Comment: @IconDaemon - "carry" is not the same as "accept for delivery" (local drug stores now "accept for delivery" Amazon orders - it doesn't mean they "carry" what Amazon sells) and the very first line of the question (not title) is literally asking "what Apple does to mitigate customer pain" which is something only Apple can answer.  I voted to close because there's just not enough material to begin with to attempt to "massage" it into being on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I initially flagged this question to be "Off Topic", but in the US, you *can* order on-line and pick up at your local Apple Store. There may be a delay, but it is possible:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any already attached version in any store (marketplace) close to me, but you really shouldn't be using what you get with that VESA mount. Sure, buy the mount but change the screws, and be prepared for apple to refuse to help if anything goes anyway, as they would have done had you used the originals.

The mount itself is branded as Apple but created by a third party making any return impossible:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MG_NRcy5mxU